# Display a gridView row information in another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a GridView in my form (FORM 1), I want when I double click on some record in it to show me all the reocrd informations in another form (FORM 2).

this is the code I use to get a dataRow from the gridView when I double click on it:

```
 private void gridControl1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[0]);
        }
```

But I don't know how can I display the row information in another form (FORM 2).

***Form1 :*** 
[image]

***Form2 :***

[image]

Comment: Pass the data in the constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Passing Data Between Forms](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/thiagu304/passdata05172006234318PM/passdata.aspx)

Basically:

```
  DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[0]);
  Form2 frm = new Form2(row);
  frm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so, it is good idea make form constructor parametrized, sometimes it brings troubles

```
  Form2 frm = new Form2();
  frm.SourceRow = gridView1.GetDataRow(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[0]);
  frm.Show();
```